# SQL week number for the whole table

Tags: sql

How to create a new column which calculates week number but for the whole table ignoring year?
Desired output is as follows:

[image]

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Week number according to what? ISO or other?

Comment: More like the output from DATEPART()

Comment: DATEPART? Which dbms has that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calculating 1st day of week of oldest row, and then calculate day diff of 1st day of week of current row and coldest row, after that, divide it by 7 days plus 1 will give you the desired week number across the full table.

Assuming you are using MySQL and the first day of the week is Sunday:

```
WITH min_week_start AS (
    SELECT
        SUBDATE(MIN(record_date), dayofweek(MIN(record_date)) - 1) as week_start_date
    FROM
       record_table
),

record_week_start AS (
SELECT
    record_date,
    SUBDATE(record_date, dayofweek(record_date) - 1) as week_start_date
FROM
    record_table
)

SELECT
    record_week_start.record_date,
    DATEDIFF(record_week_start.week_start_date, min_week_start.week_start_date) / 7 + 1 as week_num 
FROM
   record_week_start
CROSS JOIN
   min_week_start
```